# Batch File stops running after opening excel

Tags: excel, vba, batch-file

This is my first attempt at making a batch file. I am trying to achieve the following: I want to turn on a service, wait 10 seconds, open and excel file, run a macro in the excel file, then close excel file, wait 10 seconds, then turn off a service.

I have managed most of it, please see me bat file below:

```
net start "DraftSight API Service"

timeout /T 10 /nobreak

"C:\Summary report.xls"

taskkill /IM excel.exe

timeout /T 10 /nobreak

net stop "DraftSight API Service"
```

I am now at the point that upon executing this batch file that it turns on service, waits, then opens excel but will not run the macro that i have set as Auto_Open (). If i run the macro manually and close excel, the batch file then proceeds to try and close excel, which has already been closed and then executes the reset of the code.

What I want to know is why after opening excel via a batch file, why does it seem to pause the command prompt and how to get around this? Secondly how to run the macro with either the Auto_Open in excel or can I call the macro from the batch file and have it executed?

Thanks for reading and responding

Comment: I suggest to use `Woorkbook_Open` instead of `Auto_Open` Event. There is no necessary to kill excel.exe, you can add `Application.Quit` at your VBA code. Why you don't work with Schedule Task?

Comment: Once you open the excel file, the batch file is waiting for that command to complete.  In other words it is waiting for Excel to exit. It will not do anything until you close the application.

Comment: `start "" "C:\Summary report.xls"`

Comment: Thanks for the help I will try using the workbook_open command instead of auto_open. also good note on using Application.quit in my VBA macro to close workbook and continue running batch file.  Also as a note I am using this in conjunction with task scheduler. I have task scheduler run this batch file, every two hours. Then by executing this batch file wich turns on a service and then opens excel, where excel excutes a code to collect data and make a summary then close. then the batch file continues to stop the service.

Comment: Then by executing this batch file wich turns on a service and then opens excel, where excel excutes a code to collect data and make a summary then close. then the batch file continues to stop the service. The reaso I've done it this way is purely a proof of concept for me to make it work. By starting and stopping this service we are limiting the amount of data this service has been consuming. Currently this service is on all day pinging data back and forth consuming data, but all i really need is for it to retrieve data each time i want to update or add a line to the summary.Thanks

Comment: Just wanted to say I tried out the Workbook_open in conjunction with application.quit in my VBA and now I have the means of what I was trying to accomplish. thank you very much gentlemen.